# Start command prompt application/script from within Python, capture output and send input

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, subprocess, command-prompt

I've been trying to run some applications with arguments in windows command prompt, but within a Python script. I am encountering issues in understanding the subprocess module and how I could use it to send inputs, capture outputs and use the data in future functions or loops.

Let's take, for example, Windows Management Instrumentation Command-Line:

I would like to launch a command prompt from a Python script, start wmic, do some stuff then exit back to command prompt.

I know how to strat the cmd and even wmic:

```
import subprocess
cmd = subprocess.Popen(["cmd", "/K", "wmic"])
```

What I don't know is how to send commands to wmic. I have tried the following:

```
import subprocess

cmd = subprocess.Popen(["cmd", "/K", "wmic"],
                   stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                   stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                   stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

stdoutdata, stderrdata = cmd.communicate(input="product get name")
```

or

```
cmd.stdin.write("product get name")
cmd.stdin.flush()
```

Doesn't work. What I would've wanted in this example, is to start Command Prompt, start WMIC, send a command (product/process get name), capture the output of WMIC and use it to do something:

```
for line in cmd.stdout:
    if line == "some string":
        do this or do that
```

In the same time, I would like the output to be printed in the opened command prompt.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Perhaps the program is missing a newline in the "input" you send? And remember that on Windows, the newline is `"\r\n"`.

Comment: Run wmic.exe directly. Preferably run single commands. Don't try to interact with console applications in general. Most use full buffering (typically 4 KiB) when stdout is piped, which can't work interactively since the application's file buffer has to fill before it flushes to the pipe. Windows has nothing like Linux `stdbuff` to control buffering, or pseudoterminals. Recent Windows 10 has pseudoconsoles, but who can get away with only supporting the latest OS version? There are programs such as winpty that poll and scrape the console screen buffer, but that's inelegant.

Comment: @Some programmer dude: it doesn't seem to work, either

Comment: @eryksun : I don't to run wmic, it was just an example. I need to run a specific application, check out the output it gives and based on that, run some scripts.

Comment: It should be fine to use `communicate` with a batch of commands that each end with `"\r\n"`, as suggested in the first comment. They'll all be written to stdin at once, while worker threads read from the stdout and stderr pipes until the application exits. Just don't plan on being able to interact with the application, i.e. don't try to write to stdin and read from stdout sequentially, because its stdout is probably buffered -- that is, unless it has a command-line option to disable buffering or force interactive mode.